# How to import multiple csv files and create tables from their headers automatically in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgresql and sql in general. From what I understood, manually one would create the table for each file and then use copy to import the data from the csv file to the table. If we have a bunch of csv files is it possible to import and create the tables for all files using the header names in the csv file as column names ?

Thanks

Comment: Not directly using the Postgres commands. There is this though:[csvsql](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/3_power_tools.html#csvsql-and-sql2csv-ultimate-power)

Comment: It would help to include information in your question about the size of the data files and what programming language(s) you are using.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm learning it alongside django so python as well. The size of the db is 594 mbs. Following your example below do I have to write down the CREATE TABLE table (...) for every csv file ?

Comment: The second part of the example shows how the table is created  and filled with data all in one step. The file size I was interested in was that of the CSV files.

Answer (score 0):

As an example using the program I mentioned in the comment:

```
--Shows table schema creation using Postgres dialect
csvsql -i postgresql --tables cp  ~/cell_per.csv 

CREATE TABLE cp (
        line_id DECIMAL NOT NULL, 
        category VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        cell_per DECIMAL NOT NULL, 
        ts_insert TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
        ts_update TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE, 
        user_insert VARCHAR, 
        user_update VARCHAR, 
        plant_type VARCHAR, 
        season VARCHAR, 
        short_category VARCHAR
);

--Create table and import from file in one step
csvsql --db postgresql://aklaver:@localhost:5432/test --tables cp  --insert  ~/cell_per.csv 

\d cp
                               Table "public.cp"
     Column     |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 line_id        | numeric                     |           | not null | 
 category       | character varying           |           | not null | 
 cell_per       | numeric                     |           | not null | 
 ts_insert      | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 ts_update      | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 user_insert    | character varying           |           |          | 
 user_update    | character varying           |           |          | 
 plant_type     | character varying           |           |          | 
 season         | character varying           |           |          | 
 short_category | character varying           |           |          | 

select count(*) from cp;
 count 
-------
    68
(1 row)
```

This is just one tool. You could also use the I/O tools from [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/io.html).